# Copy files incrementally from S3 to EBS storage using filters

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, awk

I wish to move a large set of files from an AWS S3 bucket in one AWS account (source), having systematic filenames following this pattern:

```sh
my_file_0_0_0.csv
...
my_file_0_7_200.csv
```

Into a S3 bucket in another AWS account (target).
These need to be moved by an ec2 instance (to overcome IAM access restrictions) to an attached EBS volume incrementally (to overcome storage limitations).

### Clarification:

in the filenames, there are 3 numbers separated by underscores, like so: `_a_b_c`, where a is always 0, b starts at 0 and goes up to 7, and c goes from 0 to maximally 200 (not guaranteed it will always reach 200).

(I have a SSH session to the EC2 instance through Putty).

### 1.st iteration:

So what I am trying to do in the first iteration is to copy all files from S3,
that have a name with the following pattern: `my_file_0_0_*.csv`.
This can be done with the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_source_bucket_name/my_folder/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "my_file_0_0_*" --profile source_user
```

From here, I upload it to my target bucket with the command:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://my_target_bucket_name/my_folder/ --recursive --profile source_user
```

And finally delete the files from the ec2 instance's ebs volume with
`rm *`.

### 2.nd iteration:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_source_bucket_name/my_folder/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "my_file_0_1_*" --profile source_user
```

This time, I only get some of the files with pattern `my_file_0_1_*`, as their combined file sizes reaches 100 GiB which is the limit of my ebs volume.
Here I run into the issue that the filenames are sorted alphabetically and not numerically by the digits in there names. e.g.:

```
my_file_0_1_0.csv
my_file_0_1_1.csv
my_file_0_1_10.csv
my_file_0_1_100.csv
my_file_0_1_101.csv
my_file_0_1_102.csv
my_file_0_1_103.csv
my_file_0_1_104.csv
my_file_0_1_105.csv
my_file_0_1_106.csv
my_file_0_1_107.csv
my_file_0_1_108.csv
my_file_0_1_109.csv
my_file_0_1_11.csv
```

After moving them to the target S3 bucket and removing them from ebs,
the challenge is to move the remaining files with pattern `my_file_0_1_*` in a systematic way. Is there a way to achieve this, e.g. by using `find`, `grep`, `awk` or similar ?
And do I need to cast some filename-slices to integers first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort -V` command to consider the proper versioning of files and then invoke copy command on each file one by one or a list of files at a time.

`ls | sort -V`

If you're on a GNU system, you can also use `ls -v`. This won't work in MacOS.